# Is it right to use empty() function for checking an object is null?

Tags: php

Say,

```
$obj = $this->someFunc(); // this returns an object

if(empty($obj)){ 
    // suppose $obj is null, it does works correctly
}
```

In http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php, `empty()` is only used for variables and arrays.

But, is it the correct way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

php has the function `is_null()` to determine whether an object is null or not: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php

Answer (score 3):

`null` will cause `empty()` to return true. However, if you're checking to see if that value is actually null, [`is_null()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) is better suited for the job.

Comment: No. null != no value. In that case `empty()` is better.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (is_object($obj)) {
   // It is an object
}
```

Sorry, answered to fast. Just check:

```
if ($obj === null) {
   // Object is null
} else {
   // Object isn't null
}
```

Which is also possible to do with:

```
if (is_null($obj)) {
    // Object is null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `is_null` for checking object is null or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `is_null()` for this

Answer (score 0):

An object with no properties are not empty anymore as of PHP 5 I use isset a lot to chek that it has a value and that that value isnt NULL